# remove() removing from all items in list

Tags: python, list

.remove() has some behavior I don't understand.

```
x = [[1,2,3]]*3
x[0].remove(1)
```

then x becomes `[[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]`.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix this? I want 1 removed from the first list only.

Comment: How are you actually creating `x`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I've put in my original code

Comment: @thefourtheye your answer was helpful, you should undelete it

Comment: @thefourtheye, don't be discouraged by the odd downvote. Sometimes the downvoter just might not know as much as they think they do. If only they'd give a reason, they might learn something new...

Answer (score 4):

If you created `x` something like this:

```
a = [1,2,3]
x = [a,a,a]
```

Then the elements of `x` are actually the same object, and changing one of them causes the change to be reflected in all of them.